# Olive tree not flowering after pruning (2 years)

Tags: trees, pruning, olive

I have an olive tree that was beautiful, full of leaves and producing fruit. Well, my gardener thought it was a good idea to prune the tree 2 years ago.

The leaves never came back, only at the bottom of the tree. Now I see that the branches have black spots. Is the tree dead? What should I do?

Comment: Pictures please

Comment: Any unusual weather recently? Too hot or cold? Too wet or dry? Any sign of insects or fungus?

Comment: Olive tree is an evergreen plant, so it should have leaves (also during pruning). Maybe was the pruning caused because the olive got a freeze, and so was already half dead? In general olives had not problem with pruning, but now there are dangerous diseases (south Europe), so a picture can help us.